# Tailwind CSS custom responsive breakpoints are not working

Tags: tailwind-css, responsive

I want to make a responsive web site using Tailwind CSS and Next.js, but I can't apply my custom responsive utility classes. I added my custom breakpoints in `tailwind.config.js`.

Other media queries are working fine.

I designated `w-[600px]` in `max-1280px` and `w-[400px]` in `max-768`, but I can't apply `max-768` and another media query only applied `max-1280px`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import profile from '../../assets/images/me.jpg';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { aboutContent } from '../../data/aboutContent';

const about = () => {
  return (
    <div className='animate-fade-in-up'>
      <h1 className='text-5xl font-appleSemiBold laptopM:text-center laptopM:underline laptopM:mb-12 tablet:text-4xl'>
        About Me
      </h1>
      <div className='border-2 w-40 ml-[142px] mb-12 laptopM:hidden'></div>
      <div className='flex flex-row justify-between items-center font-appleRegular laptopM:flex-col laptopM:gap-10'>
        <Image
          className='w-[600px] tablet:w-[400px]'
          src={profile}
          alt='Picture of me'
        />
        <div className='w-6/12 laptopM:w-[600px] tablet:w-[400px]'>
          <div className='text-2xl mb-8 tablet:text-xl'>
            <p>test</p>
            <p>
              test
            </p>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div className='font-regular'></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default about;
```

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
    screens: {
      mobileS: { max: '320px' },
      mobileM: { max: '375px' },
      mobileL: { max: '425px' },
      tablet: { max: '768px' },
      laptop: { max: '1024px' },
      laptopM: { max: '1280px' },
      laptopL: { max: '1440px' },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Comment: According to the docs, you should specify your custom breakpoints in descending order, with your largest `max` value first. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#max-width-breakpoints

Comment: Thank you bro! I didn't check about that. I'll do that

Comment: @owni Did that solve the issue? If so, please make an answer and mark it correct!